# How to find log inverse in python2.7

Tags: python-2.7

```
log x=0.0795
```

How to find the value of x?. Is there any inbuilt function for log inverse in Python2.7?
Thank You.

Comment: What log are we talking about here? Natural, decadic, arbitrary?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, inverse of log function with base of e (Euler's constant) is exp. See: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/number_exp.htm

If for a log of any base, you can either convert it to base e (Remember that log_a(b) = (log_e b / log_e a)) or find the base of your logarithm, and then take power of it to the value of your logarithm. (log_a b = 3 => b = a^3)

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit weak in maths.How should I find the base of my logarithm.

Comment: x = pow(a, <result of logarithm>) => a = pow(x, 1/<result of logarithm>)

Think of this:

log_a 5 = 2 => 5 = a^2 => a = sqrt(5). Same logic.